# Assert that the correct exception is thrown

Tags: scala

I have a method `ESV.allocate(BLOCK_NUMBER + 1)` that only returns an `Exception` wrapped in a `Failure`:

```
Failure(new Exception("Tried to allocate more than available memory"))
```

However, I'm not sure how to test that.

I tried using FunSuite and I put this in my unit test:

```
assert(ESV.allocate(BLOCK_NUMBER + 1) == Failure(new Exception("Tried to allocate more than available memory")))
```

However, the test fails with this message:

```
 Failure(java.lang.Exception: Tried to allocate more than available memory) did not equal Failure(java.lang.Exception: Tried to allocate more than available memory)
```

This is probably because I am instantiating a different `Exception` object in the assert, and it doesn't compare as equal to the one returned by the method I am testing.

So how can I check the result returned by the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare classes instead of comparing absolute values.

```
assert(ESV.allocate(BLOCK_NUMBER + 1).getClass == classOf[Failure[_]])
```

if you want to check the exception message also then

```
assert((ESV.allocate(BLOCK_NUMBER + 1).getClass == classOf[Failure[_]]) && (ESV.allocate(BLOCK_NUMBER + 1).failed.get.getMessage == Failure(new Exception("Tried to allocate more than available memory")).failed.get.getMessage))
```

or

```
assert((ESV.allocate(BLOCK_NUMBER + 1).getClass == classOf[Failure[_]]) && ESV.allocate(BLOCK_NUMBER + 1).failed.get.getMessage == new Exception("Tried to allocate more than available memory").getMessage)
```

**Better solution**

```
implicit class TryUtils[A](something: Try[A]) {
  def compare[B](other: Try[B]): Boolean = {
    (something, other) match {
      case (Success(a), Success(b)) => a == b
      case (Failure(a), Failure(b)) => a.getClass == b.getClass && (a.getMessage == b.getMessage)
      case (_, _) => false
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
assert(ESV.allocate(BLOCK_NUMBER + 1) compare Failure(new Exception("Tried to allocate more than available memory")))
```

Comment: Is there a method equivalent to `failed` for `Success`?

Comment: @octavian you can do `get` directly on success like this `Success("a").get`

Comment: @octavian edited the answer with even better solution use `compare`